# Git repo structure between dev project and distribution

Tags: git, github, repository

Lets consider some **simplified structures**.

One for projects working on:

**Note the "myplugin.js"**

```
project/
├─ js/
│  ├─ myplugin.js
├─ css/
│  ├─ style.css
├─ index.html
```

I want to create a git repository to track on github all the dev of this plugin (on the current project or others comming), and to develop it with other contributors, etc... on git in a repo stuctured like:

```
.../myplugin/
├─ docs/
├─ readme.md
├─ myplugin.js
```

I can imaging doing all the dev work and changes for this plugin on the plugin repo, then import it on the projet each time, but it's painful.

How can i keep developing the plugin inside the project (or future ones), but have the history on the plugin repo (if there is a way), and without having to nest the plugin repo inside the customer repo.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

After some researches, i found a way of doing this, so i'll keep it here for people having the same question.

Hope i'll get other hints to a simpler way, without Mounting one repository inside another.

Git doc

> A submodule is a repository embedded inside another repository. The
> submodule has its own history; the repository it is embedded in is
> called a superproject.

[Submodules on Official Git doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules)